# java / spring repository / mongo - count distinct records by key

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to count number of records in mongodb distincting by one field.
I use spring data with mongo repository.
Record in mapping collection looks:

> {
>      "_id" : "1",
>      "productId" : 123,
>      "variantId" : 321
>   },
>   {
>      "_id" : "2",
>      "productId" : 123,
>      "variantId" : 3211
>   },
>   {
>      "_id" : "3",
>      "productId" : 13,
>      "variantId" : 32
>   }

I have tried in many ways and with no results.

```
@Query(value = "{distinct: 'productId'}", count = true)
Long countDistinctByProductId();
```

Code above give me always 0
Code below gave me some errors

```
Long distinctProductId();
Long findDistinctProductId();
Long distinctProductIdByProductId();
```

In mongo I i found query that gave me record with  array of distincted ids, but i cant find how to do it in java.

Answer (score -2):

Mongo Aggregation can provide the functionality that you are looking for

Here is a sample aggregation query in the mongo shell

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { $group: {_id: '$productId', count: { $sum: 1 } }}
])
```

Here is a link to the Mongo Java driver documentation  and how to use Aggregation

[Mongo Java Driver and Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)

Comment: mongo shell is not a problem - i need to use this command in spring application - using spring repository

Comment: you will be able to use the Java Mongo driver to call the aggregation query. Look at the link in my answer - it has sample code